# Apply color ramp to (QgsSingleSymbolRenderer) Simple marker

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, color-ramp

I'm using a `QgsSingleSymbolRenderer` to display various points and lines etc for a Line geometry.

I have a `Single symbol` symbology to display the last vertex as a: `Line > Marker line > Marker > Simple marker` which I'd like to colour according to one of the pre-defined colour ramps (e.g. Blues, with range between 0 - 100, based on an attribute value "count"), using PyQGIS.

I can do this manually in QGIS by opening the layer's properties and going to `> Symbology > Line > Marker line > Marker > Simple marker` where I can use the colour assistant to set the symbols fill colour based on the value of "count".  Is it possible to do this using PyQGIS?  A snippet of my current code looks something like:

```
# Define symbol layers
symbol_layers = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(vector_layer.geometryType())
symbol_layers.changeSymbolLayer(0, simple_line_symbol_layer)
symbol_layers.insertSymbolLayer(1, last_vertex_simple_marker_symbol_layer)

# Create renderer based on symbol layers, and apply to vector layer
renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol_layers)
vector_layer.setRenderer(renderer)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add sample code for **lines** and **point** layers

```
# Line Layer
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('rivers')[0]

renderer = QgsLineSymbol()

# F_CODE is the column name when I have hexadecimals colors
renderer.symbolLayers()[0].setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyStrokeColor, QgsProperty.fromField("F_CODE") );
layer.setRenderer(QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(renderer))

layer.triggerRepaint()

# Point Layer
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('airports')[0]

renderer = QgsMarkerSymbol()

# Use is the column name when I have hexadecimals colors
renderer.symbolLayers()[0].setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyFillColor, QgsProperty.fromField("USE") );
layer.setRenderer(QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(renderer))

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

**Result Lines**

[image]

**Result Points**

[image]

I hope this helps you