# Setting color of Simple Marker Layer from field using python 3

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, python-3

I'm trying to set up the colour of a QgsSimplerMarkerSymbolerLayer.

Here is my code :

```
sites=iface.activeLayer()
single_symbol_renderer=sites.renderer()
symbol=single_symbol_renderer.symbol()
symbol.setSize(4)
prop = QgsProperty()
prop.setField("Couleur")
pc = QgsPropertyCollection('Color')
pc.setProperty(4, prop)
marker_symb = QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayer()
marker_symb.setDataDefinedProperties(pc)
sites=QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayer(marker_symb)
```

But it still not working, any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this:

```
# Point Layer
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('PointLayer')[0]

renderer = QgsMarkerSymbol()

# Use is the column name when I have hexadecimals colors
renderer.symbolLayers()[0].setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyFillColor, QgsProperty.fromField("Couleur") );
layer.setRenderer(QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(renderer))

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Based on this other [response](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/323456/49538) from me

Comment: Thank you ! Very helpfull!

Comment: Answer with explanation is worth more than just code that solves the problem.